# Angular get access to value of a directive in directive

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I want to create a structural directive that queries all anchors that has "routerLink" directive in the app and and access the value of the routerLink.

I tried to implement it with this way but without success:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appShowByRole], a[routerLink]'
})
export class ShowByRoleDirective implements OnInit{

    constructor(
        private readonly elmRef: ElementRef,
        @Optional() @Inject(forwardRef(() => RouterLink)) private routerLink: RouterLink,
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (this.routerLink) {
            debugger;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `@Input('routerLink') link: any;` ?

Comment: That's great. I'll make a answer for other who's come to visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Input` to receive any attribute from template.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appShowByRole], a[routerLink]'
})
export class ShowByRoleDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input('routerLink') link: any;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `a` tags the routerLink directive class name is `RouterLinkWithHref`

Here you have both directives decorators extracted from the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts)

**RouterLinkWithHref**

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'a[routerLink],area[routerLink]', 
  standalone: true}
)
export class RouterLinkWithHref implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
...
```

**RouterLink**

```
@Directive({
  selector: ':not(a):not(area)[routerLink]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class RouterLink implements OnChanges {
...
```

I don't know exactly whats the aim of your directive, but you don't need to include the `routerlink` in you directive's selector to get the ref. Neither should you need to use forwardRef.

cheers

Comment: Thank you, I solved this by using @Input('routerLink')